# Casting from an iterator to a defined type?

Tags: c++

I am trying to construct a loop that will loop over a `std::vector` of `typedef std::pair<double, double> CFPoint` to produce sets of two points to work on.

```
if(pointList.size() % 2 == 0)
{
    CFPoint first = NULL;
    CFPoint second = NULL;
    for (std::vector<CFPoint>::const_iterator it = pointList.begin(); it != pointList.end(); ++it)
    {
        TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", it->first, it->second);

        if(first == NULL && second == NULL)
            {first = it; continue;}
        if(first != NULL && second == NULL)
            second = it;
        if(first != NULL && second != NULL)
        {
            double transitLen = sqrt(  pow((second.first - first.first), 2) + pow((second.second - first.second), 2) );
            TRACE("Distance between points: %f\n", transitLen);

            first = NULL;
            second = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Reviewing the code you might see that I use `= NULL` to signify that a `CFPoint` variable is either "ready" or not to be used. My problem is that `NULL` is defined as `0` in C++ and I cannot assign `0` to a `CFPoint`. There also is no `null` keyword in C++.

**What might my options be to set my variables as "null" or something like that to achieve the loop above?**

Hmm, while I was writing this I had the idea to use pointers in my loop rather than actual variables. You can set a pointer to `NULL`. The only issue is when trying to set `first` and `second`. I've tried to set my `first` by doing `first = &it;` but `it` is of type `iterator` how can I cast `it` to `CFPoint*`?

Comment: You can do `&*it`, which is of type `CFPoint*`. It's not casting `it` to `CFPoint*`, it's obtaining a `CFPoint*` that points to the element referred to by the iterator.

Comment: Hmm that seems to be a little closer the error goes from `cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc> *' to 'CFPoint *'` to `cannot convert from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> *' to 'CFPoint *'`? // How would `&*it` read? A pointer to the address of `it`?

Comment: Oops, sorry - you have a `const_iterator`, so `&*it` will have type `const CFPoint*` not `CFPoint*`. If you declare `first` and `second` with that type it should work hopefully.

Comment: Also there might be a little too much things named `first` and `second` in this code snippet, i don't want to imagine if you were iterating over a map :)

Comment: I'm don't see why you need any of this juggling for this loop. You appear to just walk the vector in adjacent unrelated pairs, i.e. indexes (0,1), (2,3), (4,5), etc. Why not just enum the list in steps of 2 (up to size()/2) and index each element pair?

Comment: Yeah I need to change the names, first name that popped in my head. It sure was fun writing it though hehehe. // WhozCraig, I am not sure what you mean by "enum the list". I did it that way because I could think of a different way. // @user2079303 Running the code I dont think that is the case? Could you explain why you think this is? I think its correct, but what do you see?

Comment: @AnotherUser, never mind, the code is just confusing me :) But you found what I was getting at.

Comment: Ohh yeah, I noticed that quickly. Didn't enclose the first `if`; the continue always gets hit. Fixed it in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
if (pointList.size() % 2 == 0)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; it != pointList.size(); i += 2)
    {
        const CFPoint& first = pointList[i];
        const CFPoint& second = pointList[i + 1];
        TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", first.first, first.second);
        TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", second.first, second.second);
        const double transitLen = sqrt(pow((second.first - first.first), 2) + pow((second.second - first.second), 2) );
        TRACE("Distance between points: %f\n", transitLen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your task actually doesn't require a 'null' value for a point, all you need is iterate over pairs of vector elements.

How about this:

```
if (pointList.size() % 2 == 0)
{
    for (std::vector<CFPoint>::const_iterator it = pointList.begin(); it != pointList.end(); it += 2)
    {
        TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", it->first, it->second);

        CFPoint first = *it;
        CFPoint second = *(it+1);

        double transitLen = sqrt(pow((second.first - first.first), 2) + pow((second.second - first.second), 2));
        TRACE("Distance between points: %f\n", transitLen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is that `std::pair<double, double>` doesn't
have a sentinal value and the names of its components are
probably not appropriate either.  (There's also the problem that
you've named it in a way which suggests that it is part of MFC.)
You should define your type as a class, with provisions for
a null value, if that's what you need.  This can be done either
by adding an additional `bool` which indicates whether the value
is valid or not, or by doing something tricky with NaNs.  (The
first is to be preferred, at least at the start.  The second
should be reserved as an optimization measure.)

Comment: What about `boost::optional<CFPoint>`? Admittedly that involves introducing a dependency on Boost.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz I don't generally care for the syntax; too much operator overloading abuse.  In this case, however, it might be appropriate.  But given that `double` is a POD, and that you need to create the struct anyway, to give the elements decent names, using `boost::optional` probably doesn't gain you that much.

Answer (score 0):

it->first and it->second are not pointers. They are both double. So what you are doing here:

`if(first == NULL && second == NULL)`

is checking if they are equal to 0.

Not even *it is a pointer, it is a CFPoint and not CFPoint*.

And

`CFPoint first = NULL;
 CFPoint second = NULL;`

Are also not pointers, that is why you cannot set them to NULL. Try:

`CFPoint* first = NULL;
 CFPoint* second = NULL;`

instead, and also use std::vector.

Or do this:

`typedef typedef std::pair<double, double>* CFPoint`

Answer (score 0):

The way of structuring the solution seems to be making it more complicated than is probably necessary (Jarod42's solution shows a simpler way). Running with it though you should be able to get it working by using `pointList.end()` as your guard value:

```
if(pointList.size() % 2 == 0)
{
    typedef std::vector<CFPoint>::const_iterator ConstPointIterator;

    const ConstPointIterator guardValue(pointList.end());

    ConstPointIterator first = guardValue;
    ConstPointIterator second = guardValue;

    for (ConstPointIterator it = pointList.begin(); it != pointList.end(); ++it)
    {
        TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", it->first, it->second);

        if(first == guardValue && second == guardValue)
            first = it; continue;
        if(first != guardValue && second == guardValue)
            second = it;
        if(first != guardValue && second != guardValue)
        {
            double transitLen = sqrt(  pow((second.first - first.first), 2) + pow((second.second - first.second), 2) );
            TRACE("Distance between points: %f\n", transitLen);

            first = guardValue;
            second = guardValue;
        }
    }
}
```